# Writing status to Excel file in Java using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I am able to write the status to the Excel file through my program, but there is still an issue, the status is not writing correctly to the Excel sheet. The console output is fine -

> Value of MoulikaNimmala is: Fail  key is:MoulikaNimmala Fail and 1
>
> Value of lakshman_nimmala@yahoo.com is: Pass  key
>   is:lakshman_nimmala@yahoo.com Pass and 2
>
> Value of sailakshman.nimmala@gmail.com is: Fail  key
>   is:sailakshman.nimmala@gmail.com Fail and 3
>
> Value of Keshav is: Fail  key is:Keshav Fail and 4

But the status in the Excel sheet is filling up incorrectly. lakshman_nimmala@yahoo should be filled with Pass and keshav should be filled with Fail.

```
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void readData() throws Exception {
    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Test Data";
    String fileName = "editSubscriptions.xls";
    String sheetName = "datapool";

    File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook workbook = null;

    String fileExtName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));

    if (fileExtName.equals(".xlsx")) {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    } else if (fileExtName.equals(".xls")) {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    }
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum() - sheet.getFirstRowNum();

    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i = 1; i < rowCount+1; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']")));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']")).click();

            WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("username")));
            driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear();

            driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(row.getCell(0).toString());
            driver.findElement(By.name("passwd")).clear();

            driver.findElement(By.name("passwd")).sendKeys(row.getCell(1).toString());
            driver.findElement(By.name("signin")).click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            try {
                new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='nimmala']"))).perform();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign Out']")).click();

                WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
                wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']")));
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']")).click();

                hm.put(row.getCell(0).toString(), "Pass");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                hm.put(row.getCell(0).toString(), "Fail");
                driver.get("http://in.yahoo.com/?p=us");
            }
    }  

    Set<String> keys = hm.keySet();

    int i=1;
    for (String key: keys){
        System.out.println("Value of "+key+" is: "+hm.get(key));

        String filePath1 = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Test Data";
        String fileName1 = "editSubscriptions.xls";
        String sheetName1 = "datapool";

        File file1 = new File(filePath1 + "\\" + fileName1);
        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
        Workbook workbook1 = null;

        String fileExtName1 = fileName1.substring(fileName1.indexOf("."));

        if (fileExtName1.equals(".xlsx")) {
            workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(fis1);
        } else if (fileExtName1.equals(".xls")) {
            workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook(fis1);
        }
        Sheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheet(sheetName1);
        int rowCount1 = sheet1.getLastRowNum() - sheet1.getFirstRowNum();

            Cell cell1 = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(2);
            cell1.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell1.setCellValue(hm.get(key));
            System.out.println(" key is:" + key+" "+hm.get(key) + " and " + i);
            i = i+1;

      //Close input stream
        fis1.close();

      //Create an object of FileOutputStream class to create write data in excel file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);

        //write data in the excel file
        workbook1.write(outputStream);

        //close output stream
        outputStream.close();
    }
  }
```

The problem is with identifying the row index.

Is there a way for us to identify the row index depending upon the cell value in the Excel file so that I can replace `i` in the below statement with the correct row index?:

`Cell cell1 = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(2);`

Comment: You problem has nothing to do with Selenium, that is only a distraction in this case. Have a careful read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I will read it from my next post. Do you have any solution for my problem?

Comment: Yes: Read that link, and reduce your code down to the minimum reproducible problem. To debug what you posted above, would take me the rest of today. No chance anyone here is going to do that.

Comment: @SiKing: I don't think you need to go through my code, if you understand this sentence -> Is there a way for us to identify the row index depending upon the cell value in the Excel file. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To return row number given a cell value the below code will work -

```
public int findRow(Sheet sheet, String content) {
int rowNum = 0;
for (Row row : sheet) {
for (Cell cell: row) {
    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
        if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(content)) {
                    return row.getRowNum();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;}
```